# Finding All Integers Satisfying the Condition

Tags: number-theory, inequality

Find all the solutions of the inequality-

$$\sqrt{x(\ln x +\ln \ln x)}-1 > y > \sqrt{x(\ln x+ \ln \ln x-1)}$$

Where $x,y$ $\in$ $\mathbb N$.

Determine the set of integral values of $(x,y)$.

I think for all $y$ greater than some $n$ there will always be some $x \in \mathbb R^+$ so that the inequality holds but even the proof of that seems elusive to me.

I have not made any progress regarding this problem. Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: "Determine the set of integral values". Do you mean integer?

Comment: Yes. I mean the set of values of $x,y$ where both $x$ and $y$ are positive integers.

Comment: Given x $\epsilon$ positive reals ; let y be such that x(ln(x))< e^(${((y+1)^2)/x}$)  or e^(${((y+1)^2)/x}$) <(x ln(x)/e) then (x,y) would not solve the problem.

Comment: @WilliamHilbert, what's the motivation behind this question?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your inequality has no solutions.

From the question it is clear $$\sqrt{x(\ln x +\ln \ln x)}-1 > \sqrt{x(\ln x+ \ln \ln x-1)}\Rightarrow$$ $$\sqrt{x(\ln x +\ln \ln x)}-1-\sqrt{x(\ln x+ \ln \ln x-1)}>0\Rightarrow$$ $$\sqrt{x(\ln x +\ln \ln x)}-\sqrt{x(\ln x+ \ln \ln x-1)}>1$$ But is this ever true?

Simply graphing this last inequality reveals that it is not. (Note that the $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}$ of the LHS is $0$, which is less than $1$.)